# Read the body of a Fetch Promise

Tags: javascript, node.js, fetch-api

I have the following express endpoint for uploading to Google Cloud storage. It works great and the response from the google api gives me a unique file name that I want to pass back to my front end:

```
app.post('/upload', (req, res) => {
  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm(),
  files = [],
  fields = [];

  form
    .on('field', function(field, value) {
      fields.push([field, value]);
    })
    .on('file', function(field, file) {
      files.push([field, file]);
    })
    .on('end', function() {
      console.log('-> upload done');
    });
  form.parse(req, function(err, fields, files){
    var filePath = files.file.path;
    bucket.upload(filePath, function(err, file, apiResponse){
      if (!err){
        res.writeHead(200, {'content-type': 'text/plain'});
        res.end("Unique File Name:" + file.name);
      }else{
        res.writeHead(500);
        res.end();
      }
    });
  });

 return;
});
```

I reach this endpoint by calling a short function which passes the file to it:

```
function upload(file) {
  var data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', file);
  return fetch(`upload`,{
    method: 'POST',
    body: data
  });
}

const Client = { upload };
export default Client;
```

This function is called from my front end like this:

```
Client.upload(this.file).then((data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

This final `console.log(data)` logs the response to the console. However, I don't see anywhere the response that I wrote in (`"Unique File Name:" + file.name`)

How I can retrieve this info from the response body on the client-side?

The `data` looks like this when I console.log it:

[image: Screenshot of the data console.log]

This is the response I get when I POST a file to my endpoint using Postman:

[image: Screen shot of response using Postman]

Comment: what does your `data` look like when you `console.log` it?

Comment: Added a screenshot

Comment: thanks I think I know the problem, gimme one sec

Comment: What does this `fetch('[YOURENDPOINT]').then(response=>response.text()).then(data=>{
    console.log(data);})` log to the console?

Answer (score 199, accepted):

Notice you're dealing with a [Response object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Response). You need to basically **read** the response stream with `Response.json()` or `Response.text()` (or via other methods) in order to see your data. Otherwise your response body will always appear as a locked readable stream. For example:

```
fetch('https://api.ipify.org?format=json')
.then(response=>response.json())
.then(data=>{ console.log(data); })
```

If this gives you unexpected results, you may want to inspect your response with [Postman](https://www.getpostman.com/).

Comment: I'm getting `undefined` for the `console.log(data)` if I use `response.text` or `response.blob`. I get a syntax error if I use response.json: `Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected token U in JSON at position 0`. I'm thinking the 'U' is from my 'Unique', so I think you're on the right track

Comment: Also, you wouldn't be able to see this from the screenshot I posted, but expanding the `...` for the `locked` item in the `ReadableStream` reads `false`

Comment: @quicklikerabbit What do you get when you hit your endpoint with something like Postman?

Comment: Postman returns the unique file name in the body, confirming that it is indeed there. The trick now is getting that body text out with Javascript!

Comment: Ok awesome. To be quite honest I have absolutely no clue why you're getting undefined, except that it might be some sort of misspelling error?

Comment: I just had to replace `.json()` with `.text()`, that's the solution in my case. Thanks.

Comment: There's weirdness around fetch interface, but doing response.text or json() returns body of response and not the response. Additionally it's readable only once and those methods are async. I also got undefined thinking I get the response back with readable body rather than the body.

Answer (score 31):

I had a typo in my code as pointed out by [GabeRogan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4833285/gabe-rogan) in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903767/read-the-body-of-a-fetch-promise#comment74842732_43904074):

> Ok awesome. To be quite honest I have absolutely no clue why you're getting undefined, except that it might be some sort of misspelling error?

Here's my updated code for the front end which returns the response body text:

```
Client.upload(this.file).then(response => response.text())
  .then((body) => {
    console.log(body);
  });
```

`body` is a string that reads `Unique File Name: [FILE-NAME]`

Here's a good explanation of the Fetch API and reading the response you get from the promise object: [Css tricks:  Using Fetch](https://css-tricks.com/using-fetch/).

Answer (score 10):

You can also use async/await:

When returning json content:

```
Client.upload(this.file).then(async r => console.log(await r.json()))
```

or just returning in textual form:

```
Client.upload(this.file).then(async r => console.log(await r.text()))
```

Comment: Yes, you must "await", or you’ll get a promise instead of the value you expect.

Answer (score 7):

If you are getting "undefined" for data and you are doing something with the response, make sure to return the response.

I was doing something like this

```
fetch(URL)
    .then(response => {
        response.text();
        console.log(response.statusText);
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data)); // got "undefined"
```

Return response object: **return response.text();**

```
fetch(URL)
    .then(response => {
        console.log(response.statusText);
        return response.text();
    })
    .then(data => console.log(data)); // got data
```

Answer (score 0):

I have faced this issue from a few minutes ago.

The ultimate solution is after you have the **response** you have *two helper* methods that do the job for you:

- `response.json()` will convert response into json if it was a **json** response.
- `response.text()` will get the raw text of response(use it if above failed).

**NOTE**: you will need to use await() with both of above methods.