# react native saga fetch data format issue

Tags: react-native, redux-saga

I'm using redux-saga to fetch data from a simple json-server in my React Native app. It looks like the fetch is successful, but i'm not able to extract the data i'm looking for in the response object thats being returned.
Following is my code in my generator function:

```
function* loadOpenItemsSaga(action) {
  try {
    const response = yield call(fetch, baseUrl + 'thingsList', { method: 'GET'});
    console.log('loadOpenItemsSaga successful', response);
    yield put({ type: ActionTypes.ACTION_SUCCESS, resp: response });
  } catch (error) {
    const errorMessage = { code: error.code, message: error.message };
    console.log('loadOpenItemsSaga fail', errorMessage);
    yield put({ type: ActionTypes.ACTION_FAILURE, error: errorMessage });
  }
}
```

console log printing as:

```
10:55:59:   loadOpenItemsSaga successful Response {
10:55:59:   "_bodyBlob": Blob {
10:55:59:     "_data": Object {
10:55:59:       "blobId": "eb3d53ce-ecc8-4e48-9f53-1c9b4129d300",
10:55:59:       "offset": 0,
10:55:59:       "size": 1429,
10:55:59:     },
10:55:59:   },
10:55:59:   "_bodyInit": Blob {
10:55:59:     "_data": Object {
10:55:59:       "blobId": "eb3d53ce-ecc8-4e48-9f53-1c9b4129d300",
10:55:59:       "offset": 0,
10:55:59:       "size": 1429,
10:55:59:     },
10:55:59:   },
10:55:59:   "headers": Headers {
10:55:59:     "map": Object {
10:55:59:       "access-control-allow-credentials": Array [
10:55:59:         "true",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "cache-control": Array [
10:55:59:         "public, max-age=0",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "connection": Array [
10:55:59:         "keep-alive",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "content-type": Array [
10:55:59:         "application/json; charset=utf-8",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "date": Array [
10:55:59:         "Mon, 20 Aug 2018 05:25:59 GMT",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "etag": Array [
10:55:59:         "W/\"595-QGa7N/U2dPsbWUU83//t6RMzYwQ\"",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "expires": Array [
10:55:59:         "-1",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "transfer-encoding": Array [
10:55:59:         "chunked",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "vary": Array [
10:55:59:         "Origin",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "x-content-type-options": Array [
10:55:59:         "nosniff",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:       "x-powered-by": Array [
10:55:59:         "Express",
10:55:59:       ],
10:55:59:     },
10:55:59:   },
10:55:59:   "ok": true,
10:55:59:   "status": 200,
10:55:59:   "statusText": undefined,
10:55:59:   "type": "default",
10:55:59:   "url": "http://localhost:3001/thingsList",
10:55:59: }
```

The actual content i'm expecting is:

```
    {
"thingsList": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "name":"Orange",
            "from": "Jill",
            "fromImage": "images/IMG_9352.jpg",
            "createDate": "2018-8-817:57:28.556094Z",
            "needBy": "Today",
            "description":"to put for kids box tomo, bring from down stores",
            "status": "open",
            "statusUpdatedOn": "2018-8-8T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "statusUpdatedBy": "Jack",
            "assignedTo": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "name":"Cryons",
            "from": "Jill",
            "fromImage": "images/IMG_9352.jpg",
            "createDate": "2018-8-8T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "needBy": "In a week",
            "description":"bring from opp bangle store",
            "status": "open",
            "statusUpdatedOn": "",
            "statusUpdatedBy": "Jack",
            "assignedTo": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "id": 2,
            "name":"Eggs",
            "from": "Jill",
            "fromImage": "images/IMG_9352.jpg",
            "createDate": "2018-9-8T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "needBy": "Today",
            "description": "some 10 eggs",
            "status": "open",
            "statusUpdatedOn": "2018-8-10T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "statusUpdatedBy": "Jack",
            "assignedTo": "Jack"
        },
        {
            "id": 3,
            "name": "KG sheet",
            "from": "Jill",
            "createDate": "2018-8-6T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "fromImage": "images/IMG_9352.jpg",
            "needBy": "Today",
            "description":"black n white, 1 each",
            "status": "open",
            "statusUpdatedOn": "2018-8-9=T17:57:28.556094Z",
            "statusUpdatedBy": "Jack",
            "assignedTo": "Jack"

        }
    ]
}
```

How to extract data from the Response object? response.json() isnt working

Regards,
Rashmi

Comment: Got the answer from the thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903767/read-the-body-of-a-fetch-promise