# Why is my fetch response showing a promise even after reading the response stream?

Tags: javascript, fetch

I'm calling an API, which is returning a body that I need to access. Calling the API via Postman works as expected. The JavaScript code is below:

```
async function checkIfCheater(nameToCheck) {
    let testJson = {
        "GameName" : nameToCheck
    }

    await fetch(apiGatewayCheckCheaterLocal, {
        method: 'POST',
        mode: 'cors',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(testJson)
    }).then(response=>response.json()).then(data=>{ return data; });
}
```

I have tried accessing the response in multiple ways. The example here follows [the accepted answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43903767/read-the-body-of-a-fetch-promise). However, despite this, the returned value is still a `Promise {<pending>}` object that I cannot access the body of.

How come my object is still a promise, despite following the answer on that link, and how can I fix it?

Comment: `checkIfCheater()` doesn't return anything.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be corrected as follow,

```
async function checkIfCheater(nameToCheck) {
    let testJson = {
        "GameName": nameToCheck
    };

    const res = await fetch(apiGatewayCheckCheaterLocal, {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify(testJson)
    });

    const data = await res.json();

    return data;
}

checkIfCheater('name').then(data => console.log(data));
```

Comment: I can't see anything in the log at all, not even an empty entry.

Comment: @AugustWilliams Please check your API `apiGatewayCheckCheaterLocal` there should be something with it.

Comment: The API (AWS API Gateway), shows an expected log output. The same output if I called the API with Postman.

Comment: @AugustWilliams try removing `mode: 'cors',`

Comment: Same issue as previously. API logs look fine, but `data` is undefined and still can't see anything in the console.

Comment: @AugustWilliams try to debug `res`. or move the function body inside a try-catch see whether catch got any errors.

Comment: There are no errors after putting the function inside a `try` and `catch`. Printing `res` to the log shows a locked readable stream, similar to the issue I described in the question.

Comment: @AugustWilliams Please provide your API endpoint if you can